# Build parameters are used only in pre-step

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have defined the `SELENIUM_SERVER` String Parameter for the Jenkins job.

The job also has the pre-build step:

*Invoke top-level Maven targets* which does

`install -Dproject.build.sourceEncoding=Cp1252`

and build step which also invokes Maven with the following goal

`test -DseleniumServer=${SELENIUM_SERVER}`

But when I run the job, it looks like the parameter is used only on the stage of running the pre-build step and ignored on the build step stage.

The log says the following:

`[Automation] $ /home/build/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3/bin/mvn -DSELENIUM_SERVER=<server1> install`

... and the parameter not mentioned anywhere in the context of `test`.

This results in the exception:

`org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.`

If I remove the pre-build step, the parameter is applied to the build step correctly.

How can I make the parameter applied to the build step, not only to the pre-build step?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I take it that the `install` and the `test` are configured as two different build steps. If you take a look at the [Maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) you see that `install` comes before `test` and that `"if you call a build phase, it will execute not only that build phase, but also every build phase prior to the called build phase"`.

So by running your first goal `install` the whole default lifecycle is run, including test. Since you didn't specfiy the parameter for that it fails and since it fails, the second goal `test` isn't even executed. The error is thrown during your first goal, not your second.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your exact Jenkins configuration it might be hard to come up with a precise answer, but I think I know what the answer is.

Jenkins is usually unaware of what the build steps actually do or not. It just invokes them.

You should be able to see explicitly in the log when it issues the step. I noticed you presented the log message from the prebuild step, and not from the build step

```
[Automation] $ /home/build/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3/bin/mvn 
-DSELENIUM_SERVER=<server1> install
```

However, it appears that the argument is applied here for some reason. This would normally mean that it runs through the entire maven build (including test) using that option, and you should probably succeed this first maven job.

But you say that you fail on the second step?

When you set up a maven target in jenkins, you specify some options (see under advanced)

- The goal,
- The POM and
- The properties

Ensure that under the pre-build step, you have the **install** as the goal, and a properties section with

```
project.build.sourceEncoding=Cp1252
```

On a separate line. These will be translated to a `-D` directive.

The log should still present a line with

```
mvn -Dproject.build.sourceEncoding=Cp1252 install
```

And not much more that this.

Under the build step, be certain that the the goal is **test**, and that the properties section contains only

```
seleniumServer=${SELENIUM_SERVER}
```

This should translate into

```
mvn -DseleniumServer=server1 test
```

Note that as Andre says mvn test plugin will probably not run again should it have run already. But your statement seems to contradict Andres answer.

If you believe that Jenkins is really having trouble translating the properties, try coming up with some more basic jobs for debugging purposes without Maven, such as **execute shell** and do an `echo ${SELENIUM_SERVER}` in the build or pre build, to see exactly what Jenkins do.